# need to extract link and text from the anchor tag using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on to extract link and text from from anchor tag using beautiful soup

The below code is from where i have to extract the data from anchor tag which is link and the text

```html
<a href="https://indianexpress.com/article/cities/mumbai/mumbai-vaccination-figures-surge-in-private-hospitals-stagnate-in-government-centres-7338768/">Mumbai: Vaccination figures surge in private hospitals, stagnate in government centres</a>

<a href="https://indianexpress.com/article/cities/chennai/chennai-martial-arts-instructor-arrested-following-allegations-of-sexual-assault-7339259/">Chennai: Martial arts instructor arrested following allegations of sexual assault</a>

<a href="https://indianexpress.com/article/explained/mumbai-metro-lines-2a-and-7-here-is-everything-you-need-to-know-7338637/">Mumbai Metro lines 2A and 7: Here is everything you need to know</a>
```

```
**Python code to extract the content from the above code.**
@app.get('/indian_express', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def dna_india(request: Request):
    print("1111111111111111")
    dict={}
    URL="https://indianexpress.com/latest-news/"
    page=requests.get(URL)
    soup=BS(page.content, 'html.parser')
    results=soup.find_all('div', class_="nation")
    for results_element in results:
        results_element_1 = soup.find_all('div', class_="title")
        for results_element_2 in results_element_1:
            for results_element_3 in results_element_2:
                print(results_element_3)  **The above printed html code is because of this print**
                print(" ")
                link_element=results_element_3.find_all('a', class_="title", href=True) **I am getting empty [] when i try to print here **
                # print(link_element)
                # title_elem = results_element_3.find('a')['href']
                # link_element=results_element_3.find('a').contents[0]
                # print(title_elem)
                # print(link_element)
                # for index,(title,link) in enumerate(zip(title_elem, link_element)):
                #     dict[str(title.text)]=str(link['href'])
    json_compatible_item_data = jsonable_encoder(dict)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("display.html", {"request":request, "json_data":json_compatible_item_data})


@app.get('/deccan_chronicle', response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def deccan_chronicle(request: Request):
    dict={}
    URL="https://www.news18.com/india/"
    page=requests.get(URL)
    soup=BS(page.content, 'html.parser')
    main_div = soup.find("div", class_="blog-list")
    for i in main_div:
        #link_data = i.find("div", class_="blog-list-blog").find("a")
        link_data=i.find("div",class_="blog-list-blog").find("a")
        text_data = link_data.text
        dict[str(text_data)] = str(link_data.attrs['href'])
    json_compatible_item_data = jsonable_encoder(dict)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("display.html", {"request":request, "json_data":json_compatible_item_data})
```

Please help me out with this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `main_div` tag which has all the records of news in which you can find `articles` where all data is defined and iterating over that `articles` title can be extract using finding proper `a` tag which contain title as well as `herf` of same!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res=requests.get("https://indianexpress.com/latest-news/")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

main_div=soup.find("div",class_="nation")
articles=main_div.find_all("div",class_="articles")
for i in articles:
    href=i.find("div",class_="title").find("a")
    print(href.attrs['href'])
    text_data=href.text
    print(text_data)
```

Output:

```
https://indianexpress.com/article/business/banking-and-finance/banks-cant-cite-2018-rbi-circular-to-caution-clients-on-virtual-currencies-7338628/
Banks can’t cite 2018 RBI circular to caution clients on virtual currencies
https://indianexpress.com/article/india/supreme-court-stays-delhi-high-court-order-on-levy-of-igst-on-imported-oxygen-concentrators-for-personal-use-7339478/
Supreme Court stays Delhi High Court order on levy of IGST on imported oxygen concentrators for personal use
...
```

2nd Method

Dont make so complex just observe tags what data they contain like i have found main tag `main_div` and then go for tag which contains text as well as links and you can find it in `h4` tag and iterate over it !

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
res=requests.get("https://www.news18.com/india/")

soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
main_div = soup.find("div", class_="blog-list")
data=main_div.find_all("h4")
for i in data:
    print(i.find("a")['href'])
    print(i.find("a").text)
```

output:

```
https://www.news18.com/news/india/2-killed-six-injured-after-portion-of-two-storey-building-collapses-in-varanasi-pm-assures-help-3799610.html
2 Killed, Six Injured After Portion of Two-Storey Building Collapses in Varanasi; PM Assures Help
https://www.news18.com/news/india/dont-compel-citizens-to-move-courts-again-again-follow-national-litigation-policy-hc-tells-centre-3799598.html
Don't Compel Citizens to Move Courts Again & Again, Follow National Litigation Policy, HC Tells Centre
```

...

Comment: Hi Bhavya...the above code is working but i tried the similar way in another website but its not workng

Comment: I have provided the link above in the updated question

Comment: Marking as Solved !

Comment: Did you get at which line you were wrong??

Comment: This line --> for i in main_div:
        #link_data = i.find("div", class_="blog-list-blog").find("a")
        link_data=i.find("div",class_="blog-list-blog").find("a")

Comment: yes because of `main_div` can not be iterable because of `find` method  returns tags if it is `find_all` then it returns list of elements

Comment: Thanks for your info...i got it now